# Как добавить данные в Базу Данных Django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть пустая БД (models.py описан нормально).
И есть у меня данные, которыми надо заполнить эту базу.
Как это сделать? Просто везде описано как через формы django сделать. А мне надо циклом в коде всё прописать.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Фикстуры](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata)
2. [Создание объектов](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects)

Фикстуры представляют собой обычный json файл. Ручное создание объектов может потребоваться в случае, если вы решите написать скрипт импорта (например, удобно это реализовать используя [django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)).